# meet python segmentation fault in ensurepip, but the fault is gone after inserting a print in code

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I have a python 3.7.2 on debian system.

When I run

`/3.7.2/bin/python3.7 -Im ensurepip --upgrade`

There goes the error

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

After some struggle I found that after inserting `print` in some specific line, the problem will be gone.

```
line 116 of 3.7.2/lib/python3.7/ensurepip/__init__.py:

       if verbosity:
            args += ["-" + "v" * verbosity]
        print("XXX-116 before run pip")     // this line do the magic
        return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
```

I am wondering why this happens. May someone try to find some explanation?

Comment: Probably should take this up with the maintainers of the "ensurepip" package. Create an issue on their repository? Also I am removing the `c` tag because this question has nothing to do with the C language.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya This is related to C because segment fault is due to C memory problems. The problem may be caused by the gcc or other c code that python depends on but not ensurepip package itself. The "print" statement will have no effect if it is a pure python problem.